# Graph an individual road's condition over time in a form

Tags: forms, ms-access, charts, pivot, linegraph

I have a `road_insp` query in an MS Access database:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| INSP_ID | ROAD_ID | INSP_YEAR | CONDITION |
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|       1 |     100 |      2009 |         1 |
|       2 |     100 |      2011 |      0.95 |
|       3 |     100 |      2012 |       0.9 |
|       4 |     100 |      2015 |      0.85 |
|       5 |     100 |      2017 |       0.8 |
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|       6 |     200 |      2009 |      0.75 |
|       7 |     200 |      2011 |       0.7 |
|       8 |     200 |      2013 |      0.65 |
|       9 |     200 |      2017 |       0.6 |
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|      10 |     300 |      2009 |      0.55 |
|      11 |     300 |      2011 |       0.5 |
|      12 |     300 |      2014 |      0.45 |
|      13 |     300 |      2015 |       0.4 |
|      14 |     300 |      2017 |      0.35 |
|      15 |     300 |      2017 |       0.3 |
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|      16 |     400 |      2009 |      0.25 |
|      17 |     400 |      2011 |       0.2 |
|      18 |     400 |      2014 |      0.15 |
|      19 |     400 |      2015 |       0.1 |
|      20 |     400 |      2017 |      0.05 |
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

I would like create a form that has **a record for each road**. Each record in the form would have a line graph that shows the road's condition over time.

**What I've tried:**

I can do a couple of things that are **close** to what I want:

1. I can use a `where` clause in the underlying query to limit the inspection records to include only `road #1`. While this might have the appearance of achieving what I want, unfortunately, it's not quite right. I can't navigate to the rest of the roads.

   [image]
2. Conversely, I can remove the `where` clause in the query to include all the inspection records. Again, this gives me a single record in the form, but this time it shows an average of all roads. Unfortunately, this is not what I want either:

   [image]

   [image]

---

**How can I graph an individual road's condition over time in a form?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a report, not a form.
2. Set the report RecordSource to the Road_Insp table
3. Create a GROUP in the report for the Road_ID (Insp_Year and Condition go in Detail section)
4. Put a textbox in the Road_ID group header named tbxRoad
5. Create a line chart in the group header section, just let the wizard build it with any RowSource
6. Change the chart RowSource to `SELECT Insp_Year, Condition FROM [Road_Insp] WHERE Road_ID = tbxRoad;`

Or if you really prefer a form, the form RecordSource would have to be a recordset of distinct Road_ID values, such as `SELECT DISTINCT Road_ID from Road_Insp;` or a table of unique road IDs. Then tbxRoad and the chart would go in the Detail section of form. Could not have the Insp_Year and Condition fields (or have them in a subform or listbox next to the chart).

Comment: That is a clever idea. I guess I could also just put a parameter in the underlying query of the form too.

Comment: Edited my answer.